# C: Is <limits.h> cross platform?

Tags: c, cross-platform, c99, portability

I want to write C99 or newer code that is as portable as possible. So I want to make sure that  is portable.

Comment: What do you mean cross platform? It is a standard header, but the actual values for the limits are implementation defined. Standard only mentions the minimum required values.

Comment: [Yes?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)  Did you not have such a reference?

Comment: portable code do not really exist. What can exist are applications which have been successfully ported. So writing code "as portable as possible" is an illusion

Comment: @SouraGhosh I meaned standard, sorry for the ambiguity. Now I know it's a standard C header according to AnttiHaapala 's answer

Comment: The alternative to not using `<limits.h>` is to write an equivalent header for all your targets. It is much easier to just write your  own `<limits.h>` for those targets that don't support it. (If any)

Comment: That is to say, **any compiler** where `#include <limits.h>` does **not** work, is by definition a compiler that does not conform to the C standard, i.e. the language is not `Programming languages -- C -- ISO/IEC 9899`, full stop. At some point we should a) stop caring about compilers that were written before 1989, and b) especially stop caring about compilers that were written **after 1989** but give the middle finger to any standards.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<limits.h>` is specified in the C standard. [C11/C17 5.2.4.2.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) tells what macros are available when `<limits.h>` is included. The table also lists the *smallest magnitude* of values allowed for an implementation. The actual value of each and every macro in the list is implementation-defined.

Notably, this header should be present in any standard-conforming implementation **even if** the target is a freestanding environment (i.e. does not have the services of the standard library) - e.g. [C11 draft N1570 4.6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p6):

> 6. [...] A conforming freestanding implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`. [...]

The macros are in C11/C17 `CHAR_BIT`, `SCHAR_MIN`, `SCHAR_MAX`, `UCHAR_MAX`, `CHAR_MIN`, `CHAR_MAX`, `MB_LEN_MAX`, `SHRT_MIN`, `SHRT_MAX`, `USHRT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`, `UINT_MAX`, `LONG_MIN`,
`LONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN`, `LLONG_MAX` and `ULLONG_MAX`.

Since C89 had neither `long long int` nor `unsigned long long int` the last 3 should not be present in a C89-conforming C implementation.

Comment: I'm doubtful about the "*even if the target is a freestanding environment*". Could you provide a quote from the standard saying so ? OSDec Wiki does not mention it as a freestanding header...

Comment: @user426 why'd you trust OSDev Wiki more than Stack Overflow? :D

Comment: @user426 maybe you should reread the wiki. I could *not* find a page that would not list limits.h

Comment: Ah well, you were very much right of course, limits.h is (thankfully) freestanding. I too am now seeing `limits.h` mentioned on all pages, perhaps it was just me being tired.